# how to fade in a div?

Tags: jquery, css

Go to http://earldev.tumblr.com

I am using jQuery and I can't get `fadein` to work on a `div`. I want the `div` to fade in on page load. The code I have now is

```
$('div.sc_menu').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

`div.sc_menu` is the `div` I want to fade in. (It's not working, in case you didn't get that)

Also, I am using jquery 1.4.2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('div.sc_menu').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
div.sc_menu { display: none; }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('div.sc_menu').fadeIn('slow');});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is correct as long as you make sure the elements exists when the code runs.

```
$(function() {
    $('div.sc_menu').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**EDIT:** Made it so that the `fadeIn()` will wait 2 seconds before running. You need to be using jQuery 1.4 or later to do this.

This will make sure the document is loaded before the `.fadeIn()` fires.

---

**EDIT:**

This appears to be the code from the link you provided.

```
$(function () {
     .load(function () {
     // set the image hidden by default
      $('#div.sc_menu').hide();.fadeIn(3000);
}}
```

It is malformed on several levels. Be sure to post your actual code in your question. Always helps to get the best solution.

Comment: Should I hide the div? display:none;

Comment: @Earl The problem you had was that you were using `.load()` , which is not the correct syntax for the DOM ready event handler.

Comment: @Earl - You could certainly hide it in your CSS. But if javascript is turned off in a browser, it will never be shown.

Comment: Well what I meant was do I have to hide it for the script to work? Ive been searching forever before asking this and they said I should...

Comment: @Earl - Yes, if it isn't hidden, it won't be able to fade in because it will already be visible. I suppose you could just set its opacity to 0 instead of `display none;`. Either way would work.

Comment: Ok, its not appearing at all. The CSS of the div: div.sc_menu {
position: relative;
width: 106%;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left:-52px;
margin-top:25%;
background:url('http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/Rv2l8eu6i/slice.png') repeat-x;
display:none;
} the javascript <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('div.sc_menu').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>

Comment: @Earl - Do you mean the sliding menu in the middle of the page? It appears for me. When I mouseover the items, I get a popup for each one.

Comment: @Earl - You mean the horizontal light gray bar across the middle of the page? It does, for me anyway.

Comment: ...you may want to delay the code for a couple of seconds to make the effect more obvious. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. The code seems OK to me. Try removing the "display:none;" from the CSS, to make sure that your DIV is positioned where you want it to, not overlapped by another DIV, or not off to the wrong side, or perhaps at 0 width or 0 height.

Firebug plugin for Firefox is also another great tool to observe changes to the DOM on the fly.